# How do I get the link of a current WordPress post while it is in the Loop?

Tags: php, wordpress

Below is my loop:

```
<?php if (have_posts()):
    // This function belowm is responsible for iterating through the posts
    while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            <?php wp_link_pages(); ?>
            <?php get_post_permalink(); ?>
            <?php edit_post_link(); ?>
        </div>
    <?php
        endwhile; ?>
    <?php
endif; ?>
```

Get `<?php get_post_permalink(); ?>` should display the link yet this is what is being rendered. It is not displaying the permalink of the post

[image]

Comment: The [get_post_permalink](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_permalink/) returns "The post permalink.", but [get_permalink](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/) returns: "The permalink URL or false if post does not exist."  P.S. nornally you should already have checked the docs before posting a question ... 

Comment: How do I get the link to a post?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None of the other answers are correct. `get_the_permalink()` (you can use `get_permalink()` as well, since it's an alias) **RETURNS** the data, not **ECHO**. So, it will never be printed to the screen (most WP functions with `get_` prefix work this way.)

You have two options:

1. Use `get_permalink( get_the_ID() )` pass the current post id (if not in the loop) and echo it.
2. Use `the_permalink()` which will echo out the permalink (in the loop);

`the_permalink()`:

```
<?php if (have_posts()):
    // This function belowm is responsible for iterating through the posts
    while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            <?php wp_link_pages(); ?>
            <?php the_permalink(); ?>
            <?php edit_post_link(); ?>
        </div>
    <?php
        endwhile; ?>
    <?php
endif; ?>
```

`get_permalink()`:

```
<?php if (have_posts()):
    // This function belowm is responsible for iterating through the posts
    while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            <?php wp_link_pages(); ?>
            <?php echo get_permalink(); ?>
            <?php edit_post_link(); ?>
        </div>
    <?php
        endwhile; ?>
    <?php
endif; ?>
```

This will echo out the URL, but will not make the link clickable - you need to add it to an `<a>` tag:

```
<?php if (have_posts()):
    // This function belowm is responsible for iterating through the posts
    while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            <?php wp_link_pages(); ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Click Here</a>
            <?php edit_post_link(); ?>
        </div>
    <?php
        endwhile; ?>
    <?php
endif; ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get Post Permalink you should use `get_permalink($post_id)`

[Wordpress get_permalink function Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/)

Answer (score -2):

Please try this:

```
<?php if (have_posts()):
    // This function belowm is responsible for iterating through the posts
    while (have_posts()): the_post(); 
    $id = get_the_ID();
?>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            <?php wp_link_pages(); ?>
            <?php get_the_permalink($id); ?>
            <?php edit_post_link(); ?>
        </div>
    <?php
        endwhile; ?>
    <?php
endif; ?>
```